# table row height determined by specific cell

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="first">
            <img src="ReallyLargeImage.png" />
        </td>
        <td class="second">
            One line of text<br />
            Another line of text<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first">
            <img src="AnotherReallyLargeImage.png" />
        </td>
        <td class="second">
            This<br />
            has<br />
            four<br />
            lines<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

I want the heights of `td.second` to determine the height of each row, and the images in `td.first` to scale down (keeping their size ratio) to fit that height.

It'd be nice if I could do it with just CSS/attributes to keep things neat, javascript will work too.

Comment: tables cells will size to fit their contents.  Tables are rendered from top down, left to right.  If you want a middle column to determine the height, you have to load its contents *before* the contents of the first cell.  Other than specifying the height statically, this is the only way it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.first img { display: none; }
```

**JS**

```
$("table tr").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".first img").css("max-height", 
        $(this).find(".second").height()).show();
});​
```

First you can hide the images with css so that the `height()` calculation isn't skewed by the image size. If it's not hidden the height calculation seems way off for some reason. Maybe a jQuery bug? Then once you set the `max-height` you can show the image.

---

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/c3jP6/**

Comment: some browsers scale images better than others

Comment: This forces the image's height to be 30px

Comment: are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: Yep. In light of Kirean's comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415871/table-row-height-determined-by-specific-cell#comment13439668_10415871), I think that might be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
<img style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
```

just to fit/scale automatically your image

Answer (score 0):

Do You Want to change the size of the image dynamically ? so then you have to get height of the td.second ,You cannot do that with CSS , You definitely gonna need javascript.

you can get the height of the element like this

```
var divh=document.getElementById('id').offsetHeight;
```

this work fine with a div,but I'm not sure with a table cell, any way i found some discussion in a other form ,see if you can get any help from them

[Get Table Cell Height’s with Javascript](http://dsgdev.wordpress.com/2007/03/07/get-table-cell-heights-with-javascript/)
[How to get pixel height of a div?](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=66352)

Once you get the height of the element you can set height of the image with javascript.